# value is not selected in dropdown and please convert Inline js code to external j query

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, html-select

**Hello can you  Convert inline js code to external js code so how it possible i tried but not possible.And value also not selected in dropdownlist  so how it possible ? my code is hear**

```
<select class="form-control" id="ncats" name="ncats" onchange="this.options[this.selectedIndex].value && (window.location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
    <option value="/pr192/index.php?id=10">All</option>
    <option value="/pr192/index.php?id=25">Electric</option>
    <option value="/pr192/index.php?id=15">Solar</option>
    <option value="/pr192/index.php?id=19">Real Estate</option></select>
```

Comment: Your question is very vague.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

convert inline to a function

```
<script>
    function fred(sel) {
        sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value && (window.location = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value);
    }
</script>
```

then call the function, passing `this` as the argument

```
<select class="form-control" id="ncats" name="ncats" onchange="fred(this);">
    <option value="/pr192/index.php?id=10">All</option>
    <option value="/pr192/index.php?id=25">Electric</option>
    <option value="/pr192/index.php?id=15">Solar</option>
    <option value="/pr192/index.php?id=19">Real Estate</option></select>
```

Comment: Thank you :)  but  one more problem is category value is not selected so can you help me for this

Comment: not sure what you mean ... I tested the code in jsfiddle and the function correctly read the selected options value every time

Comment: yes your code is right for convert inline to external js but my another question is value will be keep selected my problem is when selecting  Electric category then page is redirect then the value of drop down list  is different

Comment: you must have done something wrong - http://jsfiddle.net/mL9xdvfn/ this shows that the code YOU posted selects the correct value

Answer (score 0):

Javascript portion.

```
    <script>
        function convert(val) {
            val.options[val.selectedIndex].value && (window.location = val.options[val.selectedIndex].value);
            }
    </script>
```

HTML Portion

```
            <option value="/pr192/index.php?id=10">All</option>
            <option value="/pr192/index.php?id=25">Electric</option>
            <option value="/pr192/index.php?id=15">Solar</option>
            <option value="/pr192/index.php?id=19">Real Estate</option>
    </select>
```

I hope this will help you more